# How to show $f(x)=x^2\sin^2(1/x)$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: analysis

$f(x)=x^2\sin^2(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$ for $x=0$

How to show $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[-a,a]$.

I tried to use Mean Value Theorem, but couldn't finalized it.

Comment: Where are you stuck when you try to use the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable..hence Lipschiz's continuous..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find an $K > 0$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq K$, then $K$ is not that difficult to calculate. In fact, $|f'(x)| = \left|2x\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right|\leq 2|x|+1 \leq 2a+1$. So $K = 2a+1$.